# Is it possible to obtain the download progress of an dynamically loaded javascript file?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'd like to load a basic homepage for a web-app which asynchronously loads a large javascript file (the guts of the application).

Can I retrieve the download progress of this js file?

I would like to display a loading bar that accurately reflects the download progress, then when the script has finished enable a 'launch' button.

I normally use jquery but am happy for any solutions!  I'll be using a php backend if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work on all browsers, but you can use the `<progress>` tag in HTML5.

http://blog.greweb.fr/2012/04/work-in-progress/

You can also use the `progress` event for the connection.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress

Comment: Thank you, I think this will be perfect.  Do you know of a reason the blog.greweb.fr example doesn't use jQuery for the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Why show how to use .ajax if you are demonstrating XMLHttpRequest?  jQuery would be covering what is being demonstrated.